# update mySQL variable with a variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to update a mySQL variable, with the current variable's number + 1. Something like a mySQL counter every time a button is pressed.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1 = $_SESSION('value1') + "1"
WHERE condition;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to update a variable or a table column?

Comment: `SET column1 = column1 + 1`

Comment: UPDATE table SET column1 = column1 + 1 WHERE condition

Comment: `$_SESSION` is an array, not a function, access with `[]` not `()`. Also this would be open to SQL injections. Parameterize query. Trying to update `column1` or `value1`, or both?